# c# how can I make an event to cache data incoming from a UDP?

Tags: c#, arrays, events

Right now, I'm getting data from a UDP port that gives the name and a person's heartbeat incoming in realtime .

Eg.

```
Nathan,110
Bill, 105
Janet, 104
Peter, 98
Ray, 118
Sara, 101
...etc
```

I have a list of names: Alex, Bill, Carl, Dylan, Eric, Frank
I would like to have the output so that I get the difference in heartbeat between Alex and Bill, Carl and Dylan, Eric and Frank, so I have made my list the following string

```
string list="Alex-Bill;Carl-Dylan;Eric-Frank";
```

Then I split the semi-colon.

```
string[] splitList=list.Split(';');
```

Now here's where I have a dilemma and get stuck. I want to get the difference in heartbeat only between Alex and Bill, only between Carl and Dylan, only between Eric and Frank.
So, I have split each string in the array via its minus sign

```
foreach (string[] s in splitList)
{
string[] pairArray=s.Split('-');

string firstPerson=pairArray[0];
string secondPerson=pairArray[1];

if (UDPoutputData.Contains(firstPerson)==true)
{
string splitData=UDPoutputData.Split(',');
string tickerOne=splitData[1];
decimal firstNumber=Decimal.Parse(tickerOne);
}

if (UDPoutputData.Contains(secondPerson)==true)
{
string splitData=UDPoutputData.Split(',');
string tickerTwo=splitData[1];
decimal secondNumber=Decimal.Parse(tickerTwo);
}

if (firstNumber>0 && secondNumber>0)
{
decimal diffHeart=(firstNumber - secondNumber);
Console.WriteLine(firstPerson+"-"+secondPerson+"="+spread);

}
```

But, if I get the name Alex, followed by Ray, then the loop becomes confused and I have to probably wait until the right sequence comes in. Eg. I can only record it if Alex followed by Bob comes through the UDP. I'm wondering how I can go about creating an event so that an incoming heartbeat Alex gets cached and used when Bill comes in.

Comment: Guess you have to remember all incoming data first, update if it already exists and work on the cached data.

Comment: I think what Thomas is saying is, read all the data into a structure that contains people and their heart beat first (it's never a good practice to work on an incoming buffer) and then query that structure for the data you need.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, it seems easier to just create a GUI of the method I want to carry out. That way, I can enter and modify my inputs in a user friendly manner.